# how to get $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \arctan\biggr(\frac{10k}{(3k^2+2)(9k^2-1)}\biggr)=\log3-\frac{\pi}{4}$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, notation, harmonic-numbers

problem in the above asked equation of S.Ramanujan !

Hello everyone,this is a result of an entry described by ramanujan,i first request you to see the photo i have attached.

[image: click here for the image]

MY ATTEMPTION

From LHS in entry 3 in photo i shift $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to right,and for the another term i have done the following simple step

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \arctan(\frac{1}{n+k}) =\sum_{k=n+1}^{3n+1} \arctan(\frac{1}{k}) $$

MY PROBLEM

How the RHS of the above EQn is converted in the picture using taylor's theorem ?

HOW ? $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{3n+1} \arctan(\frac{1}{k})=  \sum_{k=n+1}^{3n+1} [\frac{1}{k}+O(\frac{1}{k^3})]$$

AND in the next step RHS just converted i.e. $$\sum_{k=n+1}^{3n+1} \frac{1}{k} + O(\frac{1}{n^2})$$

please help me, i dont know what is this O(x) and how it is generated from taylor's theorem ?
after that step i know how it is converted into riemann sum when limit tends to infinity i.e.

$$\sum_{k=n+1}^{3n+1} \frac{1}{k} =\sum_{k=1}^{2n+1} \frac{1}{n+k} = \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{n+k}+\frac{1}{3n}$$

now for limit tends to infinity
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{n+k}  + \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{3n}= \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{k=1}^{2n} \frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}=\int_{0}^{2} \frac{dx}{x+1} = \log{3}$$

SORRY for mistakes, this is my first question.

Comment: @M Desmond : Look up ** Big - O** Notation in Wikipedia

Answer (score 3):

We may consider that $\arctan z = \text{Im}\,\log(1+iz)$ and 
$$\arctan\left(\frac{10k}{(3k^2+2)(9k^2-1)}\right)= \text{Arg}\left[\left(1-\frac{i}{k}\right)\left(1+\frac{i}{3k}\right)\left(1-\frac{1-i}{3k}\right)\left(1+\frac{1+i}{3k}\right)\right]$$
where $-\frac{i}{k}+\frac{i}{3k}-\frac{1-i}{3k}+\frac{1+i}{3k}=0$ and by the [Weierstrass product for the $\Gamma$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)
$$ \prod_{k\geq 1}\left(1+\frac{z}{k}\right)e^{-z/k}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(z+1)e^{\gamma z}}, $$
such that
$$ \sum_{k\geq 1}\arctan\left(\frac{10k}{(3k^2+2)(9k^2-1)}\right)=\text{Arg}\left[\frac{1}{\Gamma(1-i)\Gamma\left(1+i/3\right)\Gamma(1+(1+i)/3)\Gamma(1-(1-i)/3)}\right] $$
and by invoking the reflection and triplication formulas for the $\Gamma$ function this equals
$$ \text{Arg}\left[\frac{\sinh\pi}{(2\pi) 3^{1/2-i}\frac{\pi}{3}\cdot\frac{1+i}{3}   }\right]=\text{Arg}\left[e^{i\log 3} (1-i)\right]=\log 3-\frac{\pi}{4}$$
QED.

Comment: Why $-\pi/4$ and not $+7 \pi/4$?

Comment: @RonGordon: indeed we have to be careful in picking a determination for the complex logarithm, but here we are assuming that $\text{Arg}(z)$ ranges over $(-\pi,\pi)$ for $z\in\mathbb{C}\setminus\mathbb{R}^-$.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio  in arctanz=Imlog(1+iz) what is this "Im" ?

Comment: Or we may just be careless and write the outcome as $\log 3-\frac{\pi}{4}$ plus an unknown integer multiple of $2\pi$. By a crude numerical approximation of the LHS, we may easily discover that such multiple is zero, indeed.

Comment: @MDesmond: $\text{Im}$ stands for the imaginary part.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio thanks sir but i am in high school and have not undergone complex analysis,i just wanted some explanation regarding big o notion in the pic attatched steps,but still its my pleasure to get an answer from you : )